# ORMLite for Android caching

Tags: android, core-data, ormlite

I've been using ORMLite for Android and I really like it. My question is, coming from iOS world, is there anything for ORMLite that competes with Apple's Core Data's caching? Like `NSFetchedResultsController` and `setFetchBatchSize` when querying?

I have been digging into this for some time, and i'm not finding anything. Is there any other way to enable this in the Android world?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?  What are you trying to do?  Have you seen ORMLite's internal caching?

Comment: I tried looking at that. Basically my goal is to fetch a certain number (in batches). Core data does this through the framework...is there similar functionality on Android side?